# node package name is too long for windows

Tags: npm, react-native

I was wondering if there's an option to set an alias for a certain package I'm using.

for instance , I'm using [react-native-extra-dimensions-android](https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-extra-dimensions-android) , and I get "file path too long on windows keep below 240 characters" error while building because of paths like : \node_modules\react-native-extra-dimensions-android\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png

I know I can move the local repository to a lower folder but I don't want to limit the rest of the team.
so was wondering if there's a way to change "\node_modules\react-native-extra-dimensions-android" to something like : "\node_modules\RN-dimensions-android" by some sort of configuration in package.json or any other workaround.

already [opened an issue](https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-extra-dimensions-android/issues/3) for this specific package.
Thanks